# Retrieving pointer data from Parse.com in Android

Tags: java, android, pointers, parse-platform

I'm trying to **retrieve the data from a pointer in my parse.com** database from the class User which field is "companyId" Pointer Company (It gets the company objectId from the class Company) to add that data in another table called Note into a field called companyId when creating an object.

This is my parse.com database:

Class Name: User
objectId String|companyId Pointer Company|username String |password String

Class Name: Note
objectId String| companyId String |text String

I've look for solutions and I don't find anyone as I don't know how to retrieve the companyId value as it is a Pointer.

Thanks in advance for any repply.

**EDIT:** Problem solved, below there is how it worked for me and other way of solving it by "bigdee94".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One mate helped me and here is how we solved it:

```
Note n = new Note();
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseObject userObj= user.getParseObject("companyId");
note.put("companyId", userObj.getObjectId().toString());
```

I founded kinda tricky as if you do try as:

```
Note n = new Note();
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
user.getParseUser("companyId");
```

It won't give the data in the field, I believe you get the memory access where the data is.

Thanks for your time, hope this helps more people!

Answer (score 4):

Carlos, you can try this : -

According to the docs, in order to call relational data from pointer columns you can use the include() method.
**For example:-**

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
userQuery.include("companyId");
userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
   if (e == null) {
      // userObjects retrieved successfully
      ParseObject companyIdObject = (ParseObject) objects.get("companyObjectIdColumn");
   } else {
      Log.d("objects", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
   }
});
```

Where `companyObjectIdColumn` is the `objectId` column in you `Company` table(class) and
`objects` is the queried list of objects
P.S: you can make `ParseObject companyIdObject` a global variable so that you can access it from any where.

Comment: bigdee94, Thanks for replying but I founded an easier solution as I described below. I believe it works but if I'm not wrong with your answer I would have to make another ParseQuery to get the objectId from the table Company. Even though it might help if anyone wants to do it like that.

Comment: No @CarlosRomero, You just have to call the objectId column into another ParseObject like so, `ParseObject companyIdObject = (ParseObject) objects.get("companyObjectIdColumn");`. I haven't tried it though but I believe it's logically correct. I'm glad you found a simpler solution

Comment: There's no need to cast the parse object, you can just use `objects.getParseObject("")` opposed to what you have there

Answer (score 0):

I have created pointer object and i retrieved from that easily ..Below code

```
 final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage("Loading ...");
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();
    ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(l1, l2);
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    ParseObject shop = new ParseObject("ShopLocations");
    shop.put("locationName", locname.getText().toString());
    shop.put("pin", Integer.parseInt(setpin.getText().toString()) );
    shop.put("location", point);
    shop.put("menu", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()); // this is poniter object creation in User table
    shop.put("business", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()); // this is another pointer 
    shop.put("userobjectId", user.getObjectId());
    shop.saveInBackground();
    shop.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progress.dismiss();
            if (e == null) {
                Toast.makeText(Createloctaion.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // success
            } else {
                customToast(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

*Below code for retrieving pointer object :*

```
 if(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()!=null) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ShopLocations");
        query.whereEqualTo("menu", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        query.whereEqualTo("business",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        query.whereEqualTo("userobjectId",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                    if (object.size() > 0) {
                    for (ParseObject user : object) {

                        String chkbank = user.getString("locationName");
                        Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, ""+chkbank, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    } else {
                    // Handle the exception
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });

    }
```